# good materials about event-driven programming

Tags: event-driven

I'm learning event-driven programming by Java now, but most materials are about swing. I wonder if there is any materials about event-driven programming to teach me how to make a event-driven style programming. Then I can create my on own event selection and event handling function. So could any one can tell me what is the good material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://eventdrivenpgm.sourceforge.net/event_driven_programming.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming